# Configure Binaries directory programatically when using NDepend API

Tags: c#, csproj, ndepend

When our projects are built using visual studio, the assemblies are configured to be written to output directory like "RootFolder\bin{type}{platform}". Type --> Release/ Debug and Platform --> x86/x64.
The output path is configured in the csproj file using the props file. This props file is common for all the project files as shown below.

```
<Import Project="path to CSharpProjectSettings.props" />
```

We are using **visualStudioManager.GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject(vsSlnOrProjFilePath)** to get the assemblies for analysis. We are not able to find any assemblies for analysis when the project is configured this way.

We have gone through the below links.
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-analysis-inputs-explanation#AssembliesResolving
https://www.ndepend.com/docs/ndepend-assemblies-resolving

Looks like it is possible when we are using NDepend Visual Studio plugin.

Since we are creating the NDepend project on the fly, we would like to set the Binaries directory using the code.

Can someone please help us with this?

Comment: _"Since we are creating the NDepend project on the fly"_ - why?

Comment: _"Looks like it is possible when we are using NDepend Visual Studio plugin"_ - if thats the case and you are creating (I assume generating) it, why not just compare the NDepend proj files.  Pretty sure they are text

Comment: We are using NDepend API to perform code analysis and also for comparing the analysis between different versions of the libraries. To achieve this we need to create a NDepend project on the fly. We are referring to <https://www.ndepend.com/api/NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html>. As per your suggestion we checked the NDepend proj file, its a text. We will check if we can edit the file and add the directory. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Do you need multiple NDepend projects though?  I would have thought using the _baseline_ feature would be useful to compare different versions of the libraries?

Comment: indeed with such complex scenario GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject() wont' resolve assemblies from .sln and .csproj, you can still find yourself your assemblies file paths as strings and then use @"C:\temp\MyAsm.dll".ToAbsoluteFilePath() to get a collection IAbsoluteFilePath to append to your IProject.CodeToAnalyze..SetApplicationAssemblies()  https://www.ndepend.com/api/NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam Inorder to overcome this problem, we are now processing all the project files, adding the path of the assembly and this references to the IProject.CodeToAnalyze..SetApplicationAssemblies(). When we use this method, we are seeing a difference in the list of assemblies analyzed when compared to using the GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject. The difference is we are analyzing a lot more assemblies now, but we are also missing few assemblies which were part of GetAssembliesFromVisualStudioSolutionOrProject output. Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: @sandeshnaik so far I'd advise writing an heuristic to find all assemblies needed, you could just search in all sub directories under a main directory and match all assemblies like "YourCompany.YourProduct.*"